# What is wrong with this code? Error missing ")"

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code is working as it is except for this line

```
$('#ReplenishItem').append('<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="" value="' + data[0].itemCode + '"/>\n\<input type="text" value="' + data[0].productName + '"/> \n\</td><td>\n\<select name="size">'
for (var y in data) {
    '\<option value="' + data[y].size + '">' + data[y].size + '\</option>'
}
'\</select>\n\</td>\n\</tr>');
}
```

I tried deleting the line above and it works, also tried appending without the loop and it works. I dont need the proper way to make this but hopefully the above code can work

```
var x = true;

function autoCompleteWarehouseInventory() {
    $("#productName").devbridgeAutocomplete({
        serviceUrl: 'searchWarehouseInv',
        type: 'POST',
        showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
        noSuggestionNotice: 'No Exsiting Product',
        onSelect: function (event, ui) {
            var productName = document.getElementById('productName').value;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'SetWarehouseInvServlet',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    productName: productName
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (x) {
                        $('#ReplenishItem').append('<tr>\n\
                            <th>Product Name</th><th>Color</th><th>Size</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>');
                        x = false;
                    };
                    $('#ReplenishItem').append('<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="" value="' + data[0].itemCode + '"/>\n\<input type="text" value="' + data[0].productName + '"/> \n\</td><td>\n\<select name="size">'
                    for (var y in data) {
                        '\<option value="' + data[y].size + '">' + data[y].size + '\</option>'
                    }
                    '\</select>\n\</td>\n\</tr>')
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `<select name="size">'for(var y in data){'` is not valid javascript and neither is `</option>' }'`

Comment: Maybe at first you should read something about the javascript for-in-loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in (especially look at ”Array iteration and for...in")

Comment: As a starting point it is a really good idea to JSLint your code. I spotted a few oddities with syntax. http://www.jslint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a `for...in` loop inline with a string concatenation like that.

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to format the string of `<option>` elements from `data`.

eg:

```
$('#ReplenishItem').append('<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="" value="'+ data[0].itemCode +'"/>\n\
                           <input type="text" value="'+ data[0].productName +'"/> \n\
                           <td><td>\n\
                            <select name="size">' 
                               + data.map(function(opt) { return '<option value="'+ opt.size +'">'+ opt.size + '</option>' }).join("") 
                           + '</select>\n\
                           </td>\n\
                           </tr>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use an editor that pairs up your braces and parentheses. :)

Try this:

```
var x =true;
function autoCompleteWarehouseInventory() {
    $("#productName").devbridgeAutocomplete({
        serviceUrl: 'searchWarehouseInv',
        type: 'POST',
        showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
        noSuggestionNotice: 'No Exsiting Product',
        onSelect: function (event, ui) {
            var productName = document.getElementById('productName').value;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'SetWarehouseInvServlet',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    productName: productName
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if(x){
                        $('#ReplenishItem').append('<tr>\n<th>Product Name</th><th>Color</th><th>Size</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>');
                        x = false;
                    }
                    var options = '';
                    for(var y in data){
                        options += '<option value="'+ data[y].size +'">'+ data[y].size + '</option>';
                    }
                    $('#ReplenishItem').append(
                            '<tr>'+
                                '<td>'+
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="" value="'+ data[0].itemCode +'"/>'+
                                    '<input type="text" value="'+ data[0].productName +'"/>'+
                                '</td>'+
                                '<td>'+
                                    '<select name="size">'+
                                        options
                                    '</select>'+
                                '</td>'+
                            '</tr>');
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```